# Speech Recognition to display pictures from a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, speech-recognition, picturebox

I am having an error with this Speech Recognition, I keep getting "At least one grammar must be loaded before doing a recognition" I can't get the images to display when you say its corresponding linked name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SpeechLib;
using System.IO;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SimpleSpeechRecognition
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            speechListBox1.Items.Add("Dog");
            speechListBox1.Items.Add("Elephant");
            speechListBox1.SpeechEnabled = true;

            recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
            recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

            Choices choices = new Choices("Dog", "Elephant");
            GrammarBuilder m_GrammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder(choices);
            Grammar m_Speech = new Grammar(m_GrammarBuilder);
            recognizer.LoadGrammar(m_Speech);

            recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
            recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }

        void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in e.Result.Words)
            {
                switch (word.Text)
                {
                    case "Dog":
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\" + "dog.jpg");;
                        break;
                    case "Elephant":
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\" + "elephant.jpg");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        private void speechListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //MessageBox.Show(speechListBox1.SelectedItems[0].ToString());
            SayPhrase(speechListBox1.SelectedItems[0].ToString());
            //pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\" + "dog.jpg");
            //pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(((FileInfo)speechListBox1.SelectedItem).FullName);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }


       private void SayPhrase(string PhraseToSay )
       {

                SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags SpFlags = new SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags();
                SpVoice Voice  = new SpVoice();
                Voice.Speak(PhraseToSay, SpFlags);

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors self-explanatory:

The speech engine must have a collection of 'Choices' to listen out for, however these need to be built into appropriate Grammar for the speech engine to listen out for.

```
GrammarBuilder m_GrammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder(choices);
Grammar m_Speech = (m_GrammarBuilder);
```

Then just load the grammar in:

```
recognizer.LoadGrammar(m_Speech);
```

I think that should solve your problem. It also worth noting that you can unload and load different sets of grammar via the .UnloadGrammar() function as well.

Additionally, it's also worth initializing a SpeechRecognitionEngine with an appropriate culture info. For English (UK) this is:

```
new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am a bit confused as to where I should lay each section out

Comment: kk, I am now getting two errors, "The type or namespace name 'CultureInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? and the other "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder' to 'System.Speech.Recognition.Grammar"

Comment: Ah a mis-edit on my part, the culture info also needs a using statement which is System.Globalization .

Comment: Also, assuming you are using Visual Studio, it's possible to right click erroring elements, in this case where 'CultureInfo' has the red squiggly line underneath it, if you right click, then click 'Resolve', problems caused by a lack of a using statement are appropriately fixed.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am using Visual Studio 2010 and thank you for the information I did not know that ^_^

I am now having this .NET Framework error now "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I try to run it?

Comment: Assuming you haven't altered your own code already, I believe the correct way of spelling 'recongnizer' is 'recognizer'. Try altering recognizer.LoadGrammar to be recongnizer.LoadGrammar? :P

Comment: I can't believe I had an extra n in "recognizer" thank you for that, I have changed all recongnizer to recognizer. But I am still getting this error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24631/discussion-between-lojko-and-bod4000)

Comment: This has been sorted out now, I had my system set to Japanese unicode for work, which was causing errors when talking in English. This works now since I have tried it on another system with it set to.

recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("EN-US"));

And my speech recognition set the same (US), thank you again ^_^